# Is Mojolicious's "morbo" good for production?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Is Mojolicious' **morbo** (development web server) good enough for production? Also, is **morbo** good enough to handle many http requests?

Or, must I use Apache's mod_perl for production instead of morbo?

Comment: You could have a look at "Starman" in combination with "Nginx", seems like this is a setup often used in recent projects.

Comment: pre-emptive reopen vote. And @BorisDäppen for mojo you might want to try hypnotoad+nginx

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`morbo` is the development server which comes with Mojolicious, its key feature is that it reloads the app when source files change. The production server is `hypnotoad` and that is recommended (even for high-ish loads) for *nix servers. If you aren't using *nix, then the basic `daemon` should be used, which is the underlying server that runs both `morbo` and `hypnotoad`. Read more here: http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#DEPLOYMENT

You may deploy behind a Nginx or Apache reverse proxy if you would like, proxying to hypnotoad or the daemon.

Mojolicious apps can be deployed using PSGI servers like Starman or under mod_perl or even CGI environments, but they will not be able to take advantage of several of the real-time features that Mojolicious is especially useful for, like websockets.

TL;DR, use `hypnotoad` or `daemon` for your production server.

Comment: just tried hypnotoad, but unfortunately hypnotoad is not available for Windows. But I accept as the answer because you mention about http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#DEPLOYMENT  ^^ thanks

Comment: remember that daemon is just a non-dev version of morbo, or really morbo is just daemon with an autorestart feature. Since you are correct, hypnotoad doen't work on windows, if you were considering deploying with morbo, just use daemon. Enjoy :-)

Comment: yes, I use CGI (with Apache) just for development purpose. But now I'm thinking about deployment

Answer (score 5):

i do recommend starman for mojolicious apps in production.

http://metacpan.org/pod/Starman

Comment: Real-time mojolicious features will not work when using a PSGI server. This means things like non-blocking requests and websockets will not work.